# Exit the app when back button in device is clicked

Tags: java, android, button

There are 3 activities in my app.

```
Activity A(Main Page) -> Activity B -> Activity C.
```

When submit `button` in **Activity C** is clicked, it will back to **Activity A** again. When I click the back button in device to exit the app, it will back to **Activity C** again, then **B** and **A** , then only can exit.

> Is there a way to let the app straight away exit when back button in
>   device is pressed in Activity A?

I add below code in **Activity A**, but the problem is it still  goes to **Activity C** instead of exit.

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: When you go back to activity A from C, are you using finish() to close C?

Comment: Clear activity back state whenever you want to exit from application.

Comment: @Chol no, I using intent to call A from C

Comment: Depending on what flow you want, but maybe when launch C from B, you should finish B, and then when launching back A from C you should also finish C and not create a new instance of A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your answer and comment..I have solved it by using below code

```
 public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(a);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably when you submit on activity C instead of closing it, you're opening activity A again. So do the following: start activity C for result from activity B, when you submit on activity C call setResult() and then call finish() on activity C then override onActivityResult() in activity B and when you get the result from activity C call finish () on activity B. Then you're back to activity A and if you press back, your APP will close. :) Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same situation you have. Basically I had HelloActivity(for signin/signup) and when there use had finished signing in they go to MainActivity. I didnt want the user to go to HelloActivity when clicking the back button from MainActivity. In order to do this all I had to do is just call finish() during the intent to MainActivity. heres an example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainAcivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```