# Restart app from first activity

Tags: android

In my app I have the following sequence:

```
A->B->C
```

In `C`, there is a button which upon pressing should take me straight back to `A`. The problem is that after it goes back to `A`, upon pressing back it takes me to `C` then `B` then `A` and then finally exists.

What I want is that when the app goes from `C` to `A`, pressing back should exit the program (and not take me back to `C`)

Following code in `A` does not work:

```
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Code to go back to `A`:`startActivity(new Intent(trip.this, login.class));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that `launchMode` you can add the flag: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to your `intent` to start the activity.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is that when the app goes from C to A, pressing back
>   should exit the program (and not take me back to C)

Add the following code in your Activity A.

```
   public void onBackPressed(){
            Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(a);

        }
```

Remove these two lines too. I don't think you need them.

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Comment: where to specify the new Activity name and can i specify that in manifest?

Comment: You may refer my [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367813/exit-the-app-when-back-button-in-device-is-clicked).

Comment: When I use your code it causes the program to exit completely. A never opens. Does it require any changes in manifest too ?

Comment: The `onBackPressed` method should write in **Activity A**. When back button pressed, it will exit completely.

Comment: There is no button to go back, its the physical hardware back button. Whose click event should have that code ?

Comment: Not really get it. The code worked for physical hardware back button too.

Answer (score 0):

Upon pressing the button at C, you could `finish()` the Activities C and B.

```
activityC.finish();


activityB.finish();
```